# The right way to get formatted node's body field in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal

I am wondering am I doing the right "Drupal" way in getting formatted value of node's body field. Here is my code:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
$body = '';
if (isset($field[0]['value'])) {
  $body = check_markup($field[0]['value'], $field[0]['format']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has the [`field_view_value()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) function which essentially does the same thing as your code, except it applies all of the field/instance settings to the value so you won't need to make changes to your code if you change a field setting.

You can use it like this:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');

$body = '';
if (isset($field[0]['value'])) {
  $body = field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $field[0]);
}
```

Just in case you want the default HTML wrappers included with the field output, you can use [`field_view_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) instead.